Sentence without a verb
After finishing Haury's Latin translation of The Little Prince, namely Regulus, I found another Latin version by Alexander Winkler. In Chapter 1, I noticed this sentence (in boldface):

Semper vero respondebat: «Petasus est.» Quo audito nihil iam cum eo neque de immanibus anguibus neque de vastis neque de stellis. De eis rebus, quae ad eum pertinebant, colloquebamur.

From the contexts, the main verb seems to be something like loquebam, but none is found. Is it of good Latinity to omit the main verb like this?
